# Как исправить код из книги Lippman C++ Primer использующий std::allocator?

Tags: c++

На странице 666 в последнем русском издании показан исходный код реализации простого вектора строк. В этом коде используется std::allocator а также его методы, в частности construct, который как я понял убрали с 20 версии языка. Получается что предоставленный код неактуальный на данный момент. Как его можно изменить чтобы все таки изучить тему "Классы управляющие динамической памятью"?

Вот версия исходного кода предоставленного в книге:

```
class StrVec
{
public:
    StrVec() : elements(nullptr), first_free(nullptr), cap(nullptr) {}
    StrVec(const StrVec&);
    StrVec& operator=(const StrVec&);
    ~StrVec();
    void push_back(const std::string&);
    std::size_t size() const { return first_free - elements; }
    std::size_t capacity() const { return cap - elements; }
    std::string* begin() const { return elements; }
    std::string* end() const { return first_free; }
private:
    std::allocator<std::string> alloc;
    void chk_n_alloc()
    {
        if (size() == capacity()) reallocate();
    };
    std::pair<std::string*, std::string*> alloc_n_copy(const std::string*, const std::string*);
    void free();
    void reallocate();
    std::string* elements;
    std::string* first_free;
    std::string* cap;
};

void StrVec::push_back(const std::string& str)
{
    chk_n_alloc();
    alloc.construct(first_free++, str); // ??????
}
```

Comment: Убрана только специализация `std::allocator<void>`. Остальное осталось на месте.

Comment: @StanislavVolodarskiy там выпили `construct` `destruct`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Есть несколько вариантов:

1. Выбросить аллокатор и руками звать `operator new(n)` для выделения памяти, `operator delete(ptr)` для освобождения, `std::construct_at(ptr, params)` (или `::new((void *)ptr) T(params)`) для конструирования, и `std::destroy_at(ptr)` (или `ptr->T::~T()`) для разрушения.

Использовать аллокатор имеет смысл только если класс шаблонный, и аллокатор можно заменить через аргумент шаблона.

2. Все-таки использовать аллокатор.

   Руками никакие методы (и типы из) аллокатора не звать, и для всего использовать [`std::allocator_traits`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/allocator_traits) (желательно в т.ч. для `allocate` и `deallocate`). Если бы автор книги так сделал, его код бы не сломался.

   Желательно навесить на поле с аллокатором `[[no_unique_address]]`, чтобы пустой аллокатор не занимал места.
3. Дальше, если вы хотите поддерживать произвольные аллокаторы (сделать его шаблонным параметром), то без поллитра не разберешься. **Очень аккуратно** читаем требования к [*AllocatorAwareContainer*](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/named_req/AllocatorAwareContainer) и [*Allocator*](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/named_req/Allocator). Первое - это то, чему должен соответствовать ваш класс, а второе - чтобы понимать, как пользоваться `allocator_traits`.

   В том числе:

   - `std::size_t` и сырые указатели долой, используйте `std::allocator_traits<T>::size_type`, `std::allocator_traits<T>::pointer` и прочие.
   - Копирующий конструктор должен звать [`std::allocator_traits<T>::select_on_container_copy_construction()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/allocator_traits/select_on_container_copy_construction).
   - Перемещающий конструктор должен делать `std::move` на аллокаторе.
   - Копирующее присваивание должно делать `if constexpr (std::allocator_traits<T>::propagate_on_container_copy_assignment::value)` перед тем, как присваивать аллокатор.
   - Перемещающее присваивание должно делать `if constexpr (std::allocator_traits<T>::propagate_on_container_move_assignment::value)` перед тем, как присваивать аллокатор.
   - `swap()` должен проверять `if constexpr (std::allocator_traits<T>::propagate_on_container_swap::value)` перед тем, как свапать аллокатор.
   - Операторы присваивания дополнительно должны делать хитрую проверку, если они **не** стали присваивать аллокатор (см. выше).

     ```
     if constexpr (std::allocator_traits<T>::is_always_equal::value)
         // A
     else if (alloc_a == alloc_b)
         // A
     else
         // B
     ```

     Где `A` - обычное поведение, а `B` означает, что аллкаторы "разные", и не могут освобождать память, выделенную друг другом. В случае `B`, старую память в целевом объекте нужно выбросить, и выделить заново новым аллокатором.

Answer (score 2):

Используйте `allocator_traits`:

```
::std::allocator_traits<::std::allocator<std::string>>::construct(alloc, first_free++, str);
```